# Python generator with numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, generator

I'd like to create a generator that returns a array on fly. For example:

```
import numpy as np
def my_gen():
    c = np.ones(5)
    j = 0
    t = 10
    while j < t:
        c[0] = j
        yield c
        j += 1
```

With a simple for loop:

```
for g in my_gen():
    print (g)
```

I got what I want. But with `list(my_gen())`, I got a list which contains always the same thing.

I digged a little deeper and I find when I `yield c.tolist()` instead of `yield c`, everything went ok...

I just cannot explain myself how come this strange behaviour...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because `c` is always pointing to the same numpy array reference, you are just changing the element inside `c` in the generator function.

When simply printing, it prints the complete `c` array at that particular moment , hence you correctly get the values printed.

But when you are using `list(my_gen())` , you keep adding the same reference to `c` numpy array into the list, and hence any changes to that numpy array also reflect in the previously added elements in the list.

It works for you when you do `yield c.tolist()` , because that creates a new list from the numpy array, hence you keep adding new list objects to the `list` and hence changes in the future to `c` does not reflect in the previously added lists.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative generator returns a copy of a list.  I'm retaining the `np.ones()` as a convenient way of creating the numbers, but converting it to a list right away (just once) (`array.tolist()` is relatively expensive).

I yield `c[:]` to avoid that 'current version' problem.

```
def gen_c():
        c = np.ones(5,dtype=int).tolist()
        j = 0
        t = 10
        while j < t:
                c[0] = j
                yield c[:]
                j += 1


In [54]: list(gen_c())
Out[54]: 
[[0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [2, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [3, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [4, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [5, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [6, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [7, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [8, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [9, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
In [55]: np.array(list(gen_c()))
Out[55]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [3, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [4, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [5, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [6, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [7, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [8, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [9, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think because in this generator, since I'm returning the same reference, generator yield always the same thing. If I `yield np.array(c)`, that'll work...